# How to prove that a polynomial function has single extermum in an interval?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization, proof-writing, maxima-minima

I have a function in the form of:

$$F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N x^{2a_i}-2\sum_{i=1}^k x^{a_i},$$

where $k<N$, $\forall i: a_i \in \mathbb{R}, a_i>0$.

I need to prove that this function has *at most one* (or maybe *exactly one*) critical point in the interval of $(0,1)$. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You can use Fermat's theorem: if a differentiable function $f$ has a critical point $c$, necessarily $f'(c) = 0$

Comment: If the $a_i$'s are not integers, that is not a polynomial.